# Communicating between view and view model using ReactiveUI.NET

Tags: c#, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I am fairly new to reactive UI. I am using it in my app extensively for async programming etc.

I have a question. I have a method in my ViewModel which is async and which "awaits" for a task to complete. On completion of this task, I would like to notify my  view (a UserControl) so it can dynamically add some more content/UserControls, to say, a DockPanel.

What is the best way of doing this using ReactiveUI or RX? I could use C# event mechanism , etc. but I want to continue down the RX path. I set a boolena property in my VM when the async method has "completed" (i.e. returned from await).

I then want to observe for this boolean property (defined in my VM) in my "View"..so I can attach a handler in my "View" which will dynamically create some UserControls, e.g.

```
this.viewModel.ObservableForProperty(x => x.DataLoaded)
              .Subscribe(async _ => await this.MyViewHandler()); 
// this does not compile as the delegate is not IObserver type in my view it says
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mostly got the right idea, just need some work on the syntax:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.DataLoaded)
    .Where(x => x == true)
    .Subscribe(_ => MyViewHandler());
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your very prompt reply. Thanks for jnovo too. I guess he was giving me alternative ways of doing things using Rx or TPL but I rather do it the ReactiveUI way if it is possible. I think I tried something like WhenAnyValue from my View (which is derived from Usercontrol) but the compiler did not like it. so the code above, would that go in the view?

Comment: Yes, that'd go in the View - if the compiler doesn't like it, maybe you're missing a 'using' statement? Or you're using an older version of RxUI?

Comment: Hi Paul, I am sure I have got the "using" statement to reference the right namespace. I am using ver 4.4.6 I think.

Comment: Ah. v4 doesn't have WhenAnyValue, use `WhenAny(x => x.ViewModel.DataLoaded, x => x.Value)` instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your example code is that as the compiler says, you are not passing a valid `IObserver` implementation to the `Subscribe` method. You are actually passing an `Func<boolean, Task>` where it is expecting an `Action<boolean>` implementing the [IObserver.OnNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782792.aspx).

I haven't tried ReactiveUI, but I think you can accomplish but you intend with either [Task Continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx) or with the [IObserver.OnCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782982.aspx). A couple ideas are:

- Using Task Continuation you'd launch another task once the one you mentioned has finished. You can do this by appending a `.ContinueWith` call to your task. Keep in mind that code from the continuation task modifying the UI must be dispatched to the UI thread from the continuation task (either using the `Dispatcher` or by passing the proper `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith`).
- With RX, you could create a sequence for your task with the proper `Observable.Create` factory method or simply using the [`Task.ToObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.threading.tasks.taskobservableextensions_methods.aspx) extension methods, then subscribe to it and do whatever you want on the `OnCompleted` handler.

Comment: I hate to be harsh, but if you haven't tried ReactiveUI, why would you answer a question about it? This answer is almost completely incorrect.

Comment: @PaulBetts no offense taken, from my point of view he asked either about ReactiveUI or RX so I tried to help with RX plus giving a hint about TPL. I'll gladly remove it if it doesn't apply. Now, if you point me what is incorrect I can try to fix it.